# equation of bounce function

Tags: functions

I want to create a function that acts like this:

[image]

In $t = 0$, $f(t) = 1$. When $t$ increases, $f(t)$ decreases smoothly (like an exponential function) and in the end (between say 4/5 and 1), it does a little (and fast) bounce and goes to $0$ after $t = 1$.

How can I build such $f(t)$?

Comment: does the number of bounces need to be finite? or can the size of the bounces go to zero, but the number of bounces still be infinite?

Comment: also, you could build this as a piecewise function. Does it need to be defined in just one "expression"?
and can it go to zero at the lowest point of a bounce, or should it stay >0 for every t<1?

Comment: It can be infinite, but when $t = 1$, it must be close to $0$, so I can ignore the difference and set the value to $0$. I'm using $abs(cos(3x^2)/(1+x^2))$ currently but the bounce is greater and longer than I expect.

Comment: try $cos(5{\pi \over 2}t^2)^2exp(-3t)$

Comment: Feel free to put is as an answer, it is smoother than what I am using now.